# How to check a folder for files, or else do nothing?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I inherited the following script that essentially just looks in a folder, processes the files individually, then moves them and writes to a log.

The current issue I face is that if the folder is empty, the script still creates a processing folder to move the potential files to, as well as writes to the log.   Can anyone help me modify the script such that nothing will happen if there are no files in the folder?  I know I need to do the check at the top of the script, then exit out if there are no files, but I have no experience in batch files and I am not sure how to accomplish this.

```
@ECHO OFF

set "folder=%~1"


::HERE I NEED ADD A CHECK TO SEE IF FILES EXIST.  IF THEY DO, GO THROUGH SCRIPT.  
::IF NOT, EXIT EVERYTHING

:: Set timestamp for processed folders
set TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%-         %TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%.%TIME:~9,2%

:: If more than 0 files exist begin ftp and file archival otherwise exit
FOR %%a IN (c:\Encoded_HL7_Vanderbilt\*.*) DO (

cd\"Program Files (x86)\Ipswitch\WS_FTP 12"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo %TIMESTAMP% Error switching to ftp program     directory>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%folder%\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt
goto :done)

wsftppro -s local:%%a -d Vandy!Vanderbilt:/incoming/ 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo %TIMESTAMP% Error transmitting "%%a" file to ftp     server>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%folder%\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt
goto :done)

md "E:\Processed_HL7_Vanderbilt\%folder%\%TIMESTAMP%" 2>nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo %TIMESTAMP% Error creating archive     directory>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%folder%\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt
goto :done)


move "%%a" "E:\Processed_HL7_Vanderbilt\%folder%\%TIMESTAMP%"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo %TIMESTAMP% Error moving "%%a" file to archive         directory>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%folder%\%TIMESTAMP%.error.txt
goto :done)

)

echo %TIMESTAMP% File transfers completed successfully or no files were         found>E:\HL7_Vanderbilt_log\%folder%\%TIMESTAMP%.success.txt
exit

:done 
goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dir "%~1" /a:-d /b >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel%==1 exit
```

at the *very* beginning.

Comment: Hmm..that didn't seem to work.   I put this code at the very top, right under the @ECHO OFF statement, but whenever I execute the .bat file, it still creates the archive folder (the 1st statement before the FOR loop) as well as writes to the success log (the last statement outside the loop) even if no files are in the directory.  Not sure if this matters, but I didn't mention it, but the .bat files is being called from another directory, not from the directory that the files are located in.

Comment: be sure to specify the full path name then, and it might be an error in antoher part of your code, because I tested this.